# Kendo scheduler Year view option not getting in 2016 kendo version

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo scheduler from kendo version 2016 and looking for a Year view. Is Year view available in this version? I find a demo with year view but this is not working in my case.
https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/scheduler/yearview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Year View was added to the Scheduler in Kendo UI R2 2021 (version 2021.2.511)

https://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/kendo-ui/release-history/kendo-ui-r2-2021